# How much of Australian inflation is demand driven or supply driven?

Tags: inflation, supply-and-demand, interest-rate, monetary-policy, australia

For the Aussies who have been keeping track with the current inflation rate at 5.1% we have seen the policy response by the RBA increasing the cash rate by 25 basis points so its now at 0.35%. This is the first time it's been done in, I think, 10 years, so it is a pretty big change of limbo.

However, as a student, I am more keenly interested in how much of the inflation is driven by demand versus supply but I haven't kept my horses steady in these past few weeks. Admittedly, I have been sloppy on the news and trends so I am a bit behind.

Comment: Inflation during what time period? Also if you are asking about literally now it’s too early to say. Macro statistics are usually published with 2-4 quarter lag and to analyze what is driving things like inflation rigorously you might need micro data that are published even with greater lag so if you are asking about 2022 there won’t be serious answer till 2024-2025 I reckon

Comment: @1muflon1 Ah i see. Yeah I was talking abt the current inflation rate.

Comment: ok but inflation is always defined over unit of time. By current you mean this month quarter half a year a year last two years? All of it could be considered current